# OData (WCF Data Services) Continuation on a query that uses projection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an OData query that looks like this:

```
var query = entities.MyObjects.Select(x => new {x.MyObjectID, x.Number, x.Name});
```

When I run it I get only 100 items back.  That is because my server is setup to page at 100 items.

But there are quite a few more and I need them all at once (in just this one occasion).

**How can I get them all?**

**NOTE:** I have tried to follow the [Continuation examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/02/02/server-paging-in-data-services.aspx) on the web, but they all use a `DataServiceCollection<T>`.  Since I am using projection, I don't have a valid type to put in there.

I read through this page: [How to: Project Data Service Query Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650917%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but it did not help either as it is not using anonymous types.

Is this possible?  I don't want to bring back all of the object (it is quite large and there is no need to waste the bandwidth or memory doing that.)

Comment: @Brandon - Thanks for the comment.  I ended up doing this.  If you post as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Take and Skip with multiple queries.

Similar too:  [WCF Data Service - How to set Page Size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146631/wcf-data-service-how-to-set-page-size-programmatically)

```
var query = entities.MyObjects.Skip(200).Take(100).Select(x => new {x.MyObjectID, x.Number, x.Name});
```